# Rxjs keep subscription open

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

When I subscribe to an observable retrieved from firebase it completes and closes by it self even thought there is no error and the angular component is still active. I am using Angular v12, firebase v8 and Rxjs v6

```
this.firebaseCard = this.cardService.getCard(this.deckId, this.cardId);
this.testsub = this.firebaseCard.subscribe(card =>
{
    if(!card)
    {
        console.log('invalid card');
        return;
    }

    this.name.setValue(card.name);
},
error => console.log(error),
() =>
{
    console.log('why');
});

this.testsub.add(() => {
    console.log('why');
});


public getCard(deckId: string, cardId: string): Observable<ICard>
{
    return this.afStore
        .collection(DECK_COLLECTION).doc<IDeck>(deckId)
        .collection(CARD_COLLECTION).doc<ICard>(cardId)
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(changes => {
                const data = changes.payload.data();
                const id = changes.payload.id;
                    
                return { id, ...data };
            }),
            first()
        );
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I prevent my subscription from closing?

Comment: I believe you want `valueChanges` as opposed to `snapshotChanges`.

Comment: Also, you added `first()`, which means you're making the Observable complete after its first emission.